# Using pandas .apply to while loop through every row of the dataframe to get to intended substring given starting and ending index of a string

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, pandas

I have a function called `postprocess` that applies while loop condition to find for `-` and `alphabets` to each dataframe row. `postprocess` looks like this:

```
def postprocess(description, start_index, end_index):
      if (start_index > 0) & (start_index < len(description)):
        while bool(re.match(r"\w|\'|-", description[start_index - 1])) & bool(
            re.match(r"\w|\'|-", description[start_index])
        ):
            start_index = start_index - 1
            if new_start == 0:
                break
      description = description[new_start:new_end]
      return description
```

For example the `description` is `credit payment velvet-burger` and the `start_index` is 7 and `end_index` is 12. So `description[start_index]` will be `b` Which is the `b` in `burger` will be run in a while loop by tracing backwards to return the target substring we want to see because `burger` is not complete as we want the word `velvet-` also.
After running `postprocess` we will get `velvet-burger`.
The complete code looks like this:

```
df["target_substring"] = df.apply(lambda x: postprocess(
                         x["description"], x["start_index"], x["end_index"]+1),
                         axis=1)
```

Is there a better way to write this code?

Comment: Why using *bitwise and* `&` instead of explicit **`and`** ?? Also, fix indentations in your code

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions**](https://CodeReview.Meta.StackExchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest `bitwise and &` is used instead of `and` is because both operators gives expected results thus no second thought has been put into this. I applied black formatting to my code and it is hard to adjust indentations to what it is in real python format while grouping the code in the ``` section.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question but it sounds interesting. Can you please give a self-contained example program that I can run that demonstrates the expected output?